# Spring security login error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I just implemented a simple login functionality using spring it how ever worked with the eclipse in built browser but gives the following error in chrome and firefox.

```
HTTP Status 404 - /SpringLogin/welcome.jsp;jsessionid=8332D4F3D4709DCA37C87F30F1EA03D5
The requested resource (/SpringLogin/welcome.jsp;jsessionid=BEE789093FF79CB6B67F8DA368E8B3E4) is not available.
```

can you please tell me why it is happening?

PS: I have two projects SpringLogin and both of them had same project names and both had similar packages. Then neither of the projects worked properly and gave the above error. How ever after I created another project with a different name and using different package names, it worked like magic. I am guessing here that it may have been the problem. But what is the logical answer that'll explain what happened there?

Answer (score 0):

you don't have being calling the correct URL

it seems that the context /SpringLogin/ does not exists anymore.

Try /welcome.jsp or if you changed the name of application - try /newappname/welcome.jsp